# Database query for timeline of a social networking site

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a social networking site and notice board system for my college.

I want to show 10 to 15 most recent posts from the friends of the LoggedInUser in Home Page.

If I select all the rows of timeline table in from database, then it will consume more memory and also fetch posts which are not of the friends of the LoggedInUser.

So what should be the best possible way to do so?

Help Me.

The table "friends" stores the UserID, FriendID and status.
The table "timeline" stores the posts of all the users with PostID and UserID

I'm using Apache, PHP and MySQL.

Thanks...

Comment: Have you considered adding a timestamp to the timeline table so you can search for the latest post and count backwards the number of latest posts for the given userID.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look into SQL joins pretty carefully before you go build a social network. I'm not gonna lie. This is a very basic question that you should be able to answer on your own (without Stack Overflow) if you're planning on building a social network of any kind.

That said, here are two queries that would work. And you might try experimenting with both and reading up on the difference between the two, as well as the performance implications of using one vs the other. I should also mention, these will give you the PostIDs you need, but you'll need to join those with a posts table (presumably) to get the actual post content. I leave that step up to you.

Also, in terms of getting the 10-15 most recent posts, you need to ask yourself a question... can you even answer that question with the tables you've listed?

Hint: You can't. Question: Why not?

**Query Option 1 (gets all the post ids belonging to friends of friends.UserId = ???):**

```
SELECT b.postid, b.userid
FROM friends AS a
INNER JOIN timeline AS b
ON a.FriendID  = b.userid
WHERE a.UserID = ???
```

**Query Option 2 (gets all the post ids belonging to friends of friends.UserId = ???):**

```
SELECT b.postid, b.userid
FROM timeline AS b
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM friends 
WHERE friends.UserID = ??? AND b.UserID = friends.FriendID)
```

Now, a question for you: Do both queries above return the same result? Is one preferable to the other? If so, is it always preferable or does it depend on the circumstance? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

1. add timestamp to specify the posts that you want to show.
2. if you are building a social network website NEVER select all rows (youll face security problems, injections and so forth if youre putting it online)
3. if you are mixing PHP and HTML together do an IF- ELSE statement: IF they are friends display posts of friends that are in your *friends table* with the value *1*.

hope this helps, Ive also built a social network site for school project.